# Is there a way to prevent content caching or scraping from an API?

Tags: web-scraping, caching, api-gateway, apigee

Imagine the following situation. I have an API and a developer builds an application that retrieves new content from it on a daily base. She stores this content and provides this data to all the instances of an app she developed. In this way these apps do not have to call the API directly.
Is there a way to prevent this and force the apps (and therefore the end users) to use the API and not only the application on the server.
I found many questions about how to cache API data but not how to prevent that. I am fairly new to this, so maybe I am overlooking something or maybe it is not possible to prevent this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is now clear to me that there is no simple solution to this and it is a general problem and it is not only applicable to API's. The best option is to handle this contractually. Thank you @evansche .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apigee for API-management, you have some options. First, consider the options available to you contractually, if this is that sort of business relationship and you can impose certain API behavior with a business partner through a contract.

Separate from the legal side of things, we remember that you control your API and the credentials you issue for use by your API clients. You cannot though control, practically, what a client developer does with the credentials you issue: she could promise to embed the credentials in the mobile apps' API client, but change her mind and use it centrally, and then design her mobile client to call into her central cache. If though you really insist that only mobile app clients should be calling your API and not a hub/cache server, then you could consider applying constraint policies on your API (within the Apigee proxy, such as [Access Control](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/access-control-policy)). For instance, you could blacklist your partner's hub/cache server IP address, although that is weak security at best. Or, you could apply a constraint that only clients with certain identifying User-Agent strings (mobile OS, client) are allowed to connect to your API. Or use GeoIP filtering to allow only clients from certain regions, if that applies to your use-case.

Finally, depending on the data model, you might be able to rate-limit such that a bulk cache becomes impractical: if your edge-client use-cases is to fetch a single record, but a cache would have to hold thousands of records, then you could impose a per-client rate limit ([Quota policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy)) which is no bother to individual mobile clients, but makes the work of a hub/cache server untenable.